# How to sum unknown number of td values

Tags: jquery

I have a table that could have 1 row or up to 13 rows or so. (In this case I'm only using 3) Using an MVC Razor foreach table. I need to find a way to sum the values of a specific class of tds on the fly.

I know this topic has been solved and talked before, but none seem to work for me.  I've tried things like.

```
 var total = 0;
$("td.mcalPremium").each(function () {
    total += parseFloat($(this).text());
});
console.log(total);
```

I get 0 returned.

tried variations of the same thing with no success.

Posting a pic of the table. I need to sum the values in the premium td's and display it in the empty textbox below. These values are derived from this function.

[image]

```
$("#alSublineValSubmitTBL").on('input', 'td:nth-child(11)', function () {
var td = $(this);
var input1 = +td.find('input').val() || 0;
var input2 = +td.parent().find("td:nth-child(10) input").val() || 0;

var exp = parseInt(input1);
var rate = parseFloat(input2);
var premium = rate * exp;
var parseGross;

var Altable = $('table#AlCommissionTable > tbody ');
Altable.find('tr#Almcal').each(function (i) {
    var $altds = $(this).find('td'),
        GrossPremium = $altds.eq(2).text();
    parseGross = parseFloat(GrossPremium);
});


var p = $('.my-popper');
var percentage = (parseGross * 3) / 100;
var plusGross = parseGross + percentage;
var minusGross = parseGross - percentage;

if (premium < minusGross) {
    td.parent().find('.mcalPremium').val(accounting.formatNumber(premium, 2)).addClass('bg-primary text-white');
 );
} else if (premium > plusGross) {
    //display premium in premium field
    td.parent().find('.mcalPremium').val(accounting.formatNumber(premium, 2)).removeClass('bg-primary').addClass('bg-danger text-white');
} else {
    td.parent().find('.mcalPremium').val(accounting.formatNumber(premium, 2));
}
```

});

The premium field is auto updated based on the values in the other two fields. I need to take premium values, sum them and display the total in the empty text box.

As always your help is greatly appreciated.

Updating to show the HTML

```
  <div class="row pr-2 pl-2 pb-3 mcalSublineCard" id="MCAL">
    <div class="col-12" id="cardMcal">
        <div class="card bg-secondary">
            <div class="card-header bg-info" id="mcalHeader">
                <h4>MCAL <span id="success"></span></h4>

                <h5 class="float-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up fa-1x" onclick="userMoveScreenTop();"></i></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <table class="table table-striped" id="alSublineValSubmitTBL">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr class="text-center">
                            <th>SubLine</th>
                            <th>Symbols</th>
                            <th>Limits</th>
                            <th>Deductible</th>
                            <th>Rating Basis</th>
                            <th>Rate</th>
                            <th>Exposure</th>
                            <th>Premium</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            Up = item.UniqPolicy;



                            ULT = item.UniqLineType; //validating Line specific Guid.

                            if (ULT == AL)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="hideMe">
                                        @* 0 *@
                                        <span id="locs" class="mcalLineType">
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UniqLineType, new { id = "lineType" })
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="hideMe">
                                        @* 1 *@
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UniqCifId)
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="hideMe">
                                        @* 2 *@
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UniqPolicy)
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="hideMe">
                                        @* 3 *@
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UniqSublineType)
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="font-weight-bold mcalSubLineNames">
                                        @* 4 *@
                                        <span class="mcalSubLineNames">
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubLine_Name)
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="border border-danger mcalSymbols" style="max-width:8%;">
                                        @* 5 *@
                                        <div class="row" style="max-width:8%;">
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <span class="mcalSymbols">
                                                    <select class="selectpicker form-control ddlMcalSymbols" data-width="fit" multiple title="symbols" name="ddlMcal" id="ddlMcalSymbols"
                                                            data-selected-text-format="count > 5">

                                                        <option value="61">61</option>
                                                        <option value="62">62</option>
                                                        <option value="63">63</option>
                                                        <option value="64">64</option>
                                                        <option value="65">65</option>
                                                        <option value="66">66</option>
                                                        <option value="67">67</option>
                                                        <option value="68">68</option>
                                                        <option value="71">71</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </span>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <span id="ddltest"></span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="border border-danger mcalLimits" style="width:12%;">
                                        @* 6 *@
                                        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center pr-2">
                                            <select class="ddlmcalLimits form-control ddlSubLines">
                                                <option value="0" selected="selected">Select Limit</option>
                                                <option value="300000">$300,000</option>
                                                <option value="500000">$500,000</option>
                                                <option value="750000">$750,000</option>
                                                <option value="1000000">$1,000,000</option>
                                                <option value="2000000">$2,000,000</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @* 7 *@
                                        @Html.DropDownList("mcalDeductibles",   new List<SelectListItem>
                                        {
                                            new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "0"},
                                            new SelectListItem { Text = "$500", Value = "500"},
                                            new SelectListItem { Text = "$1000", Value = "1000"},
                                            new SelectListItem { Text = "$2500", Value = "2500"},
                                            new SelectListItem { Text = "$5000", Value = "5000"},
                                            new SelectListItem { Text = "$10,000", Value = "10000"}
                                        }, new { @class = "form-control mr-2 ddlSubLines" } )
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        @* 8 *@
                                        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center pr-2">
                                            @Html.DropDownList("mcalRatingBasis",   new List<SelectListItem>
                                          {
                                              new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "none"},
                                              new SelectListItem { Text = "ACV(Actual Cash Value)", Value = "ACV"},
                                              new SelectListItem { Text = "Miles", Value = "Miles"},
                                              new SelectListItem { Text = "Payroll", Value = "Payroll"},
                                              new SelectListItem { Text = "Revenue", Value = "Revenue"},
                                              new SelectListItem { Text = "Stated Value", Value = "Stated Value"},
                                              new SelectListItem { Text = "TIV(Total Insured Value)", Value = "TIV"},
                                              new SelectListItem { Text = "Unit", Value = "Unit"}
                                          }, new {@class = "form-control mr-2 ddlSubLines" } )
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="mcalRate " style="width:10%;">
                                        @* 9 *@
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control subLineInputs" pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?" step="0.0001" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="" style="width:12%;">
                                        @* 10 *@
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control subLineInputs mcalExposure" id="mcalExposure" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="" style="width:13%; ">
                                        @* 11 *@
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control mcalPremium subLineInputs" />
                                        <div class="my-popper">Premium is higher than listed premium</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            }

                        }
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="" style="width:13%; ">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control total" id="AlLineTotal" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer bg-secondary">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-3">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md float-left mr-3 p-2" id="alSubmitButton">Submit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md p-2" id="addComments" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mcalComments">Comments</button>
                        <textarea class="form-control collapse m-3 mcComments" id="mcalComments" rows="3" onkeyup="countChar(this)"></textarea>
                        <span class="charNum ml-3" ></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-9 text-black">
                        <label class="d-inline-flex float-right customcheckPsmp pb-3 ">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="minPremium" value="true" name="minPremium" id="alminPremium" />
                            <span class="checkmarkPsmp"></span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="d-inline-block float-right text-black mt-2">Min-Premium Used</label>
                        <h4 class=" d-inline-flex mr-2" id="lblCommission"> Commission Info</h4><i class="d-inline-flex fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-2x" style="cursor: pointer" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#reviewAllMcalBtn"></i>

                        <div class="collapse mb-2" id="reviewAllMcalBtn">
                            @Html.Action("GetLineCommissions", "Trucking", Up)
                        </div>
                        <div class="float-right cbMinPremium">



                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div
```

EDIT. I've been playing with this all morning and still struggling to get the correct values added. One of two things is happening.

Option 1. I've tried with the given answers and get some behavior I'm not sure how to handle. When I use this method I get some odd addition that I can't understand. 
You'll see the Premium amount is different than the console.log number.

```
var total = 0;
var prem = td.parent().find("td:nth-child(12) input").val();
var str2 = '';
$(".mcalPremium").each(function () {
    str2 = prem.replace(",", "");
    total += parseFloat(str2);
});
console.log(total);
```

[image]

Option 2. I'm getting right values, but it's not adding them. It's merely displaying the last Premium value I'm trying to add. You can see the console.log displays all values as they're inputted and ends on the final input.. But it does the same thing for all three. Doesn't actually add the values .

```
var total = 0;
var total1 = 0;
var str2 = '';
$('.mcalPremium').each(function () {
    var prem = td.parent().find("td:nth-child(12) input").val();
    str2 = prem.replace(",", "");
    total = parseFloat(str2);
});

total1 += total;
console.log(total1);
```

[image]

Comment: can you please share the HTML code as well?

Comment: @ Nidhin Joseph I added the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to combine many of the answers out there and fool with them to make them fit with what I was doing. I needed the textboxes to sum only when the user reached the last td in the last row.

I use last-child and call a sum function when it reaches. Add and remove color classes based on some conditional logic. Works exactly as needed.

```
$('#alSublineValSubmitTBL > tbody > tr:last-child').focusin(function () {
    var line = "AL";
    displayPrem = CheckTotal(line);
    if (displayPrem > plusGross) {
        $('#AluserPremium').text(accounting.formatNumber(displayPrem, 2)).removeClass('perfectGross').addClass('highGross');
    }
    if (displayPrem < minusGross) {
        $('#AluserPremium').text(accounting.formatNumber(displayPrem, 2)).removeClass('highGross perfectGross').addClass('lowGross');   
    }
    if (displayPrem > minusGross && displayPrem < plusGross) {
        $('#AluserPremium').text(accounting.formatNumber(displayPrem, 2)).addClass('perfectGross');
    }
});
```

Determine the sum

```
function CheckTotal() {
var checkTable = $("table#alSublineValSubmitTBL >tbody");
var totals = [];
var total = 0;
checkTable.find('tr').each(function () {
    var $cTds = $(this).find('td'),
        prem = $cTds.eq(11).find('input').val();
    totals.push(prem.replace(",", ""));
});
var sTotal = 0;
$.each(totals, function (i, val) {
    total = parseFloat(val);
    sTotal += total;
});

  return sTotal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wiuthout seeing the HTML  it is difficult to answer - but from the code you have provided - it appears that the tds that display the premium, actually house inputs that have the class of mcalPremium and the value of these inputs are what you are setting in the above code. So what you want to retrieve is the val of each of these inputs.

note that the following will target all the elements (inputs)  with the stated class- irrespective of the td'd that they are in and will therefore sum the value of each.

```
 var total = 0;
$(".mcalPremium").each(function () {
    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
console.log(total);
```

Comment: `Without seeing the HTML it is difficult to answer...` in that case, why would you attempt an answer without confirming the requirements?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph - because of this code that was provided "    td.parent().find('.mcalPremium').val(accounting.formatNumber(premium, 2)).addClass('bg-primary text-white');
 );" which indicates that there is a td that has an input that is given a value and given classes that would style the input to be awfully asimilar to the provided image. And because I know stuff.

Comment: you could go `$("td.mcalPremium input")` direclty instead if that's the case

Comment: I added the HTML for you to see

Comment: @NidhinJoseph - nope - because my suggestion is premised on the idea that the element that has the mcalPremium is the input not the td........ which would not be targetted by your suggested selector. I would suggest that rather than second guessing my solution - you provide one of your own and if you are right then I am wrong and thats ok....

Comment: @NidhinJoseph - and gavgrif scores..... !!!!.... <input type="text" class="form-control mcalPremium subLineInputs" />

Comment: not in for an argument mate, even in your answer, it's clear there is uncertainty. If not, you don't need the second code snippet.

Comment: @gavgrif thanks for the help. I've tried your approach and tried modifying it with little success. Your approach brings back NaN.. I've been playing with this all morning and found some success and the reason why I was getting NaN.. but now the issue is one of two things. I'll edit my post above and explain what is happening.

Comment: The NaN indicates that you are not parseing the values to a number before the calculations.Always remember that the value of an input (even a type="number" input) is ALWAYS a string. It is probably better to use ParseInt as well - rather than parseFloat. I hope you get to the bottom of it. Heppy coding.